# Still able to clone git repo while ssh-agent is down

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh-agent

I have created ssh key pair. Started ssh-agent on ubuntu, added the key into the agent and put the public key to github account. Was able to clone the repo with no password. The only thing I cannot understand, why I still able to clone the repo after reboot or when ssh-agent is down?

Comment: If you don't have a passphrase on your private key, ssh-agent is not necessary.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you.